# File sharing between OSX Lion (10.7) and OSX Tiger (10.4)

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I recently purchased an iMac with OSX Lion already installed. My parents have an iMac running 10.4 Tiger. I have been trying to file share between the two but when I try to open the dropbox (from Tiger) it says I do not have permission, yet I cannot find anywhere on Tiger to grant the permission.

I'm sure there is something simple and easy I am missing but I can't find it?

Comment: this has really nothing to do with the OS'es version, as eyemyth noted.

Answer (score 3):

You can't open the Drop Box - just like a physical drop box. You can put files in it, but you can't open it or see what's there.

If you want to browse files on the Tiger machines, click "Connect as" and type in the username and password of an account on the Tiger machine.

Comment: okay well that is a little lame. so there is no way to file share between the two?

Comment: You can, you just have to connect as the user who owns the files on the remote Mac.

Answer (score 1):

On your Tiger machine, open System Preferences, Sharing. Turn on Filesharing and write down the server address of your machine. It will be "afp://...something".

Now from your Lion OSX desktop, open the "Go" toolbar and press connect to server. Enter the "afp://" address into the address line.

You will be prompted by a window asking for the name and password to login to. Enter the username and password of the account on the Tiger machine that you want to access.

Your Lion OSX should open a window asking which volume you want to mount. Click the hard disk.